# How to save persistent objects databound to a DataLayoutControl (DevExpress tools)?

Tags: .net, devexpress, xpo

I have a small form displaying the DataLayoutControl component.

If I use a GridControl the objects get saved. If I use the DataLayoutControl (which shows them individually) they do not get saved after they are changed. The underlying object is changed after the user interface edits, but doesn't get saved.

How can I enable this ?

PS: I have tried UnitOfWork.CommitChanges (i have one uow going through the whole architecture) to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a Session and an XPCollection on the form where the DataLayoutControl is. You should hook XPCollection with Session. You select the right class for the XPCollection and maybe add some criterial that make the XPCollection return zero records. Hook XPCollection to the DataLayoutControl.

Then you should provide a constructor with a parameter: The Oid of the object you want to edit. Inside the constructor you should use the Criteria to make the XPCollection contain only that object. Make sure you call Session.Save() in your Save button or menu item.